# Dynamically changing vlookup table

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I recorded this:

```
Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(VLOOKUP(RC1,sorted!R3C1:R35C33,8,FALSE)="""","""",VLOOKUP(RC1,sorted!R3C1:R35C33,8,FALSE))"
```

I need to have it update dynamically.

I found this (modified for my needs), but I'm not sure what to put in the "?" fields. Hopefully I'm on the right track:

With Worksheets("Move to New")

```
.Range("?").Offset(x, 0) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
         .Range("?").Offset(x, 0), _
         Worksheets("sorted").Range("?", .Range("?").End(xlDown)), 8, False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it resolved.

Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(VLOOKUP(RC1,sorted!C1:C33,8,FALSE)="""","""",VLOOKUP(RC1,sorted!C1:C33,8,FALSE))"